# Split a CSV file using AWK, while reading from a different file for naming the output files

Tags: shell, csv, awk

I have a CSV file as the following:

```
group1, item1
group1, item2
group2, item3
group1, item4
.....
```

I have managed to split this file by groups to separate csv files (group1.csv.dat, group2.csv.dat etc.). Each file contains all items belonging to a specific group.

group1.csv.dat:

```
item1, true
item2, true
item4, true
.....
```

group2.csv.dat:

```
item3, true
.....
```

I have used the following AWK:

```
awk -F, '{print $2",true" > $1".csv.dat"}' file1
```

Now, I have a second file (let's say file 2), as follows:

```
group1, GRFS+NC, 4
group2, GRTU+NC, 6 
....
```

How can I read this file using AWK in order to name the files created in the first step as
GRFS4.csv.dat, GRTU6.csv.dat instead of group1.csv.dat, group2.csv.dat? Preferably, I would like to incorporate processing into the first step. Many thanks...

Answer (score 1):

```
awk -F, '{split($2,a,"+");print $2",true" > a[1]""$3".csv.dat"}' file2
```

Comment: Be careful, trailing spaces will appear in file names.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. This will produce files based on information from file2 only. What I would like to do is essentially rename the files produced by the AWK in my question (e.g. take group1.csv.dat, lookup for "group1" in file2 and rename group1.csv.dat to GRFS4.csv.dat by concatenating the relevant fields).

Comment: As discussed many times previously, un-parenthesized concatenation on the right side of output redirection produces undefined behavior. You need to put brackets around it. Also, the null string (`""`) between `a[1]` and `$3` is doing absolutely nothing.

Answer (score 0):

You need something like this, untested:

```
awk '
NR==FNR{ name[$1] = $3 $6 ".csv.dat"; next }
{ print $2 ",true" > name[$1] }
' FS='[, +]' file2 FS=',' file1
```

Just count the fields in file2 to make sure $3 and $6 are the correct fields. Add a debugging for loop to print them all to see if you're not sure.